# Java Swing image cut off/zoomed

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, javax.imageio

when I try to render a `png` image in Java Swing, it is cut off/zoomed on all sides. Here is my code:

```java
this.setSize(500, 500);
this.setResizable(false);
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
this.setVisible(true);
this.getGraphics().drawImage(getImage("IMAGE PATH"), 0, 0, this);
```

And this is my `getImage` function

```java
public static Image getImage(String path) {
        File file = new File(path);
        try {
             return ImageIO.read(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The image I want to render is 500x500, just like my frame, but it still comes out wrong. This also applies to when I use the function like this:

```java
Image image = getImage("Image Path");
assert image != null;
JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
```

Here is one of the images I am trying to render:
[image]

Here is the outcome:
[image: Outcome]
It is kind of hard to tell from this example, but the ground should be lower and the trees higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't set the size of the frame**

If your image is 500x500 then how can you expect the image size and frame size to be the same when the frame also has a title bar and borders?

**Don't do custom painting**`

Instead:

1. create a JLabel with an ImageIcon.
2. Add the label to the frame
3. invoke `pack()` before making the frame visible.

All the components will get the proper size.

Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Labels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) for more information and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Even though @camikr found a solution, I found a better one for my needs.

What I did, was I created a new `JPanel` and ran `setPreferredSize` with the dimensions of my `JFrame` (500x500). Then I overrided the `paintComonent` function to render the image using the `Graphics2D` class.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Objects;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    public Image loadedImage = getImage("Image");
    public LoadState() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2.drawImage(loadedImage, 0, 0, null);
        g2.dispose();
    }
}
```

EDIT: Fix what @Harald K suggested

Comment: As `getImage` involves I/O, it's a very bad idea to invoke it from the `paintComponent` method, as the image will be loaded over and over each time the panel is repainted, making your app feel sluggish... Instead, initialize your panel with the image already loaded, and override `getPreferredSize` to return the dimensions of your image to avoid hardcoding... Or just use a `JLabel`. 

Comment: Good to know, I will change that in my code.